# JSOUP not compatible with JS - receiving blank HTML-elements

Tags: jsoup

In Java I´m connecting to a website and requesting the HTML document:

```
public void anyAction() {
        new HttpThread().start();
}
```

```
class HttpThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String url = "http://example.com/something" //this is a dummy. You can´t access the real website without a VPN
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                    .timeout(30000)
                                    .get();
                // rest of the code
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // print e.toString()
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
}
```

This is the requested HTML-code of the website, which includes a bit of javascript:

```
<html><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>This is the title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="header">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="attr1" class="attr1"><div class="test">something</div></div>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody></table>
        <div id="attr2" class="attr2" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr3" class="attr3" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr4" class="attr4" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr5" class="attr5" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr6" class="attr6" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr7" class="info">something</div>
        <div id="attr8" class="attr8" style="visibility: visible;">something</div>

        <script language="javascript">

            function getParam ( strParamName ) {
                strParams = document.location.search.substring ( 1 , document.location.search.length );
                varParams = strParams.split ( '&' );
                for (var intPos = 0; intPos < varParams.length; ++intPos ) {
                    varParam = varParams[intPos].split ( '=' );
                    if ( varParam[0] == strParamName ) {
                        return varParam[1];
                    }
                }
            }


            function loadData (url) {
                var mydata = null;
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (json) {
                        mydata = json;                  ;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        mydata = null;
                    }
                });

                return mydata;  
            }

            function initialize () {                

                display = new Object();             
                refreshRoomInfos();                         
                insertData();
                timer = window.setInterval ( "insertData()" , 30000 );
                timer = window.setInterval ( "refreshRoomInfos()" , 60000 );

            }

            function refreshRoomInfos() {

                var displayId = getParam('displayId');
                var virtualNowDate = getParam('virtualNowDate');
                var preview = getParam('preview');
                var roomRestUrl;

                if (typeof displayId === "undefined" || displayId === "") {                 
                    roomRestUrl = '../rest/displayService/get/rooms?roomId=' + getParam('roomId');
                } else {
                    roomRestUrl = '../rest/displayService/get/rooms?displayId=' + displayId;                    
                }

                roomData = loadData(roomRestUrl);
                if (typeof roomData !== "undefined" && roomData != null) {
                    var room = roomData[0]; 

                    if (typeof room !== "undefined" && room != null) {
                        var attr1 =  room.displayName;              
                        if (typeof attr1 === "undefined" || attr1 === "") {                     
                            attr1 = room.name;                                      
                        }
                        display.roomId = room.id;        
                        fillHTML('room', "<div class=\"test\">" + attr1 + "</div>");

                        if (typeof room.additionalDisplayText !== "undefined" && room.additionalDisplayText != null) {
                            fillHTML('attr7', room.additionalDisplayText);
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }

            function insertData() {
                if (typeof display.roomId !== "undefined") {

                        + "&virtualNowDate=" + virtualNowDate
                        + "&preview=" + preview

                    var apptURL = '../rest/displayService/get/appointments/' + display.roomId + '/50?displayFlag=false';
                    var virtualNowDate = getParam('virtualNowDate');
                    if(virtualNowDate){
                        apptURL += "&virtualNowDate=" + virtualNowDate;
                    }
                    var preview = getParam('preview');
                    if(preview){
                        apptURL += "&preview=" + preview;
                    }
                    var appointments = loadData(apptURL);
                    var appointment = getCurrentAppointment(appointments);              
                    if (appointment != null)  {

                        setVisibleHTML('attr2', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr5', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr6', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr3', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr4', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr8', 'hidden');

                        var belosEvent = appointment.event;

                        // Titel des Appointments
                        var title = appointment.displayTitle;
                        if (typeof title === "undefined"
                                || title === "") {
                            title = belosEvent.attr4;

                            if (typeof appointment.subattr4 !== "undefined" && appointment.subattr4 !== ""
                                    && appointment.subattr4 !== title) {
                                title += " - " + appointment.subattr4;
                            }
                        }

                        // Startdatum des Appointments
                        var dateFrom = moment(appointment.startDate).toDate();
                        var dateFromString =
                                dateFrom.getHours()
                                + ":"
                                + (dateFrom.getMinutes().toString().length === 1 ? "0" + dateFrom.getMinutes() : dateFrom.getMinutes());
                        // Enddatum des Appointments
                        var dateTo = moment(appointment.endDate).toDate();
                        //    dateTo.setTime(appointment.endDate);
                        var dateToString =
                                dateTo.getHours()
                                + ":"
                                + (dateTo.getMinutes().toString().length === 1 ? "0" + dateTo.getMinutes() : dateTo.getMinutes());
                        //falls mehrtägiger Termin
                        if(!(dateFrom.getDate()===dateTo.getDate()&&dateFrom.getMonth()===dateTo.getMonth()&&dateFrom.getFullYear()===dateTo.getFullYear())){
                            //falls Date-Parameter über URL übergeben wurde
                            if(paramD!==null&&paramD!==undefined){
                                //falls heute nicht zwischen Terminbeginn und Terminende oder nicht der der letzte Tag des mehrtägigen Termins ist
                                if(!((!(now.getDate()===dateFrom.getDate()&&now.getMonth()===now.getMonth()&&now.getFullYear()===dateFrom.getFullYear())&&
                                        !(now.getDate()===dateTo.getDate()&&now.getMonth()===dateTo.getMonth()&&now.getFullYear()===dateTo.getFullYear)&&
                                        dateFrom.getTime()<now.getTime()&&now.getTime()<dateTo.getTime())||
                                        now.getDate()===dateTo.getDate()&&now.getMonth()===dateTo.getMonth()&&now.getFullYear()===dateTo.getFullYear())){
                                    now = paramD;
                                }
                            }
                            //falls heute erster Tag, dann behalte Startuhrzeit bei, ansonsten setze sie auf 00:00
                            dateFromString = dateFrom.getDate()===now.getDate()&&dateFrom.getMonth()===now.getMonth()&&dateFrom.getFullYear()===now.getFullYear() ? dateFromString : "00:00";
                            //falls heute letzter Tag, dann behalte Enduhrzeit bei, ansonsten setze sie auf 23:59
                            dateToString = dateTo.getDate()===now.getDate()&&dateTo.getMonth()===now.getMonth()&&dateTo.getFullYear()===now.getFullYear() ? dateToString : "23:59";
                        }

                        // Organisator des Appointments
                        var attr6 = belosEvent.attr6.lastname;
                        if (typeof belosEvent.attr6.firstname !== "undefined"
                                && belosEvent.attr6.firstname !== "") {
                            attr6 += ", " + belosEvent.attr6.firstname;
                        }
                        if (belosEvent.attr6.lastname === "System"
                                && belosEvent.attr6.firstname === "System") {
                            attr6 = null;
                        }

                        fillHTML('attr2', dateFromString + " - " + dateToString + " Uhr");

                        fillHTML('attr6', attr6);
                        fillHTML('attr4', title);

                    } else {
                        setVisibleHTML('attr2', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr5', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr6', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr3', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr4', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr8', 'visible');

                    }   
                }               
            }

            function setVisibleHTML(fieldId, visible) {
                //alert(fieldId);
                var elem = document.getElementById(fieldId);                
                elem.style.visibility = visible;
            }

            function fillHTML(fieldId, value) {             
                var elem = document.getElementById(fieldId);                
                elem.innerHTML = value;
            }

            function getCurrentAppointment(appointments) {
                var appointment = null;
                var now = new Date();   
                var virtualNowDate = getParam('virtualNowDate');
                if(virtualNowDate){
                    now = virtualNowDate;
                }
                console.log("virtualNowDate " + virtualNowDate);
                console.log("NOW " + now);
                if (appointments != null && appointments.length > 0) {
                    console.log("appointments not null and length > 0 ");
                    for (var i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {
                        appointment =  appointments[i];                     
                        if (appointment != null && now <= moment(appointment.endDateWaiting).toDate()) {
                            return appointment;
                        }
                        appointment = null;
                    }                               
                }
                return appointment;
            }

            initialize();

        </script>




</body></html>
```

then I´m extracting the text content of the elements by their `id` `attr1` - `attr8`:

```
doc.select("div[id=attr1]").text();
```

It works for `attr1`, `attr3`, `attr5` and `attr8`.

The problem is that the text content I receive from `attr2`, `attr4`, `attr6` and `attr7` is blank. It should not be so, since they´re not blank when I open the website on my webbrowser.
I guess it has to do something with the javascript part in the HTML-code, since JSOUP is not compatible with javascript. 
Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML that is returned from URL: `"http://example.com/something"`, which is the URL that is named in your code looks like this, ***BOTH*** in my Google-Chrome web-browser 'View-Source' window, ***AND*** in my downloaded-scraped HTML `out.html` file.

**SUGGESTION:** Please update your code such that the HTML you have specified/provided is consistent with the HTML that may be retrieved from the URL named in your question's code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>


</body></html>
```

Just to point out, that it does not appear to have any of the HTML divider elements (and therefore, the 'attr1' attributes) that you are searching.  Perhaps you have entered the wrong URL?

Comment: The URL is a dummy. You can´t access the real website without a VPN. Thanks for the note - I edited the question